# How to send notification to a particular employee using signalR

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I am working on a crm where Jobs are assigned to employees automatically and when a job is created application looks for the employee with maximum idle time.I am able to broad cast notification to all the employees but I want to know how to send notification to the employee for which job is assigned.Just like facebook each user recieves his notifications only.I am using this statement in hub class

```
   Clients.All.broadcastMessage( message);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently broadcasting your messages to everyone I suggest you use`Clients.User(userid)`

Get the current logged in user `string userName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;`

And then to send out notification to the particular user you can have something like.

`Clients.User(userName).broadcastMessage(message);`

Answer (score 0):

You have to recognize user depending on connectionId.

Here is a good blog post describing this:

http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/mapping-asp-net-signalr-connections-to-real-application-users

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this just 3 days ago, and finally got it working.

Suppose you have a Hub class called YourHub, your javascript code should look like this

```
$(function () {
    var yourHub = $.connection.YourHub;
    yourHub.client.OnMessage = function ( message) {
        console.log(message):
    };
});
```

Then you need to implement IUserIdProvider on the server, which receives a IRequest (there should be a cookie or something for you to identify the person), and implement the method

```
public string GetUserId(IRequest request)
```

Then as Izzy told you use Clients.User(userId).OnMessage(message)
where userId is the id you return on the GetUserId and OnMessage is the method in your javascript file.
Be carefull to use Clients.User(userId) not Clients.Client(userId)

Comment: Its getting messed up could you please give me clear idea regarding  this as i am new to signalR.